# Table Rate Message Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time

Tags: magento-1.9, table-rates

I am getting the error as `"Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time."`

My table Rate data is as follows :

```
Country Region/State    Zip/Postal Code Weight (and above)  Shipping Price
IN  *   *   500 120
IN  GUJAR   *   500 100
IN  MAHAR   *   500 80
IN  *   *   250 70
IN  GUJAR   *   250 55
IN  MAHAR   *   250 55
```

If i order any product of the weight it is displaying this message.

I tried on local server with default magento template but it is working fine. Please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Answer . 
I made changes to Ship to specific countries to all countries and Now it is displaying. 
Don't know whether it is a bug or not. But now the rates from table rates are now displaying.